# How can I install a postgres extension via an ActiveRecord migration when rails runs as a non-superuser?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, security, activerecord, postgis

I am running a Rails app with a Postgres database.

I would like to add Postgis to my installation, so part of what I need to do is run a `enable_extension "postgis"` from an ActiveRecord migration. I can't do that though because the user that Rails uses to connect to postgres is a non-superuser. This is important because we are using Row Level Security which requires we connect as a non-superuser.

I figured I could upgrade to the latest Rails where there is support for multiple databases. Now that I have upgraded, I am trying to run this `enable_extension "postgis"` via a privileged postgres account.

I changed my `database.yml` to have this locally:

```
development:
  primary:
    database: mos_development
    host: postgres
    username: rails
    password: rails
    adapter: postgis
  superuser:
    database: mos_development
    host: postgres
    username: admin
    password: admin
    adapter: postgresql
    migration_paths: db/migrate/superuser
```

And I have a migration that contains:

```
class AddPostgisExtensionToDatabase < ActiveRecord::Migration[7.0]
  def change
    ActiveRecord::Base.connected_to(shard: :superuser) do
      enable_extension "postgis"
    end
  end
end
```

But I get the error:

```
PG::InsufficientPrivilege: ERROR:  permission denied to create extension "postgis" (PG::InsufficientPrivilege)
HINT:  Must be superuser to create this extension.
```

so I verified that I can connect to postgres as the `admin` user and run the command `CREATE EXTENSION postgis;`, so I think the issue is that ActiveRecord is not using the expected database connection in the migration.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Why not just install the extension as the admin before your deployment— there is no reason to    Create it in a migration.